# How do you say when you learned from something?

Tags: kanji, sentence

If I want to say that I learned from something, Can I use like this?
For example:

> この小説を読むと、いろいろなことわざを学びました。

Or there are other Kanji that I can use?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

A common way to express it is 勉強になる - "to gain knowledge; to be illuminated, enlightening; informative; illuminating" (definition from EDICT). As in 勉強になりました.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will note that down in my book :D